How to inherit material when using geometry nodes?
I'm trying to figure out how to get GN to use the input geometry's material, and... I just can't get it to work.
Here's a really simple setup:

(I'm using the default scene, but using this with any mesh shows the problem. Just set the object's material to something that's clearly distinguishable from the default. Toggling display of the GN modifier makes it clear that the material is set on the unmodified object but not the GN-produced mesh.)
What changes need to be made to this setup to get the GN output to use the input object's material?
(Note: this is somewhat overly simplified. Ultimately, I would like something that works on curve objects sans the Mesh to Curve node. However, as I only need it to work on line segments, I was hoping that using mesh edges instead of curves might work better. Alas, no such luck.)

Add a Set Material node after the Curve to Mesh one and click on the Material field to select the material?

@JohnEason, I want to use the material set on the input geometry... not have to specify a material separately via the GN modifier.

I'm not that familiar with GN, but I'm surprised that the Object Info node doesn't have a material output that could be used. I suppose that would be a problem if there's more than one material on it though.

@JohnEason, me too! There really ought to be such a node (probably one that takes a geometry and a material index and spits out a material).

You can make such a node using existing tools

@MarkusvonBroady, how? The only node I see that outputs a material is the one that takes it from an input constant/port. Please consider explaining in an Answer.

You can't output a material but you can set it on geometry by joining and setting mat index

(Using Blender 4.2.4)
The default material (with index 0) can be transferred to mesh generated inside a GeometryNodes modifier by joining the generated geometry and the input geometry (see dark pink nodes), that can be deleted after if needed (see dark blue nodes). The input geometry must be the first input of the Join Geometry node.

Resources:

Blender file (4.2.4+): 
About GN modifier attached to curves, see Use material assigned to curve in geometry nodes.


Argh... I want to break something now. One of the reasons (I suspect) I couldn't get this to work is because when I converted my curves to mesh, Blender removes the material.  AFAICT there's still no way to accomplish this with curves, however.

With curves, one workaround (not very satisfactory however) is to input the material through the Group Input node to use it with a Set Material node. It just means that the material "name" is not hard coded inside the GN graph, but it is not really inherited.
